# Installing Ubuntu/Debian on a running remote server (Without BIOS Access and Live CD)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, remote, vps

Currently I have this case, I have a dedicated server that has several attached disks, one of them a 350GB SSD and a 2TB HDD.

The 350GB disk is covering the entire /root partition so I need to reduce that partition to only 30GB and leave the remaining free for other purposes.

I can only access the server via SSH and the only other option is to enter rescue mode with GRML.

It seems that the host provider (WorldStream) only gives me the option to enter rescue mode to GRML and when I exit it reinstalls Ubuntu regardless of whether it works or not. And the administrative panel does not allow me to configure the partition size or partitioning through there.

So it should only do it by starting Ubuntu and restarting it after the configuration is done

Reducing the current running partition I think it is impossible, so I wanted to do the plan B of installing it on the second hard disk, start it as the main system, and then modify the partitions of the first disk and then reinstall it, but somehow I feel that I would have problems with the GRUB of the first disk, I could be wrong, is it possible to do it? I'm not sure how many things I need to install during the process

Taking into account that the SSD, that is, the first disk is the one that will always run, and having a first partition of BIOS BOOT on that disk.

```
Device Start End Sectors Size Type

/dev/sda1 2048 4095 2048 1M BIOS boot

/dev/sda2 4096 488394751 488390656 232.9G Linux filesystem
```